# Angular Get Error When Using Reactive Form However it works but there is red line error appear

Tags: angular, typescript

that's is my `TSConfig.json`

[image]

and this is `Package.json`

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^16.0.3",
    "@angular/cdk": "^16.0.3",
    "@angular/common": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^14.2.0",
    "@auth0/angular-jwt": "^5.1.2",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^14.0.1",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.7",
    "@swimlane/ngx-charts": "^20.3.1",
    "alertifyjs": "^1.13.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.2",
    "jquery": "^3.6.4",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^10.2.0",
    "ngx-cookie-service": "^16.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.5.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^14.2.7",
    "@angular/cli": "~14.2.7",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^14.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.3.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "tslib": "^2.6.2",
    "typescript": "^4.7.4"
  },
  "description": "This project was generated with [Angular CLI](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli) version 14.2.7.",
  "main": "karma.conf.js",
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

My We Site Work Correctly Without any Error.
Otherwise I get an Red line Error.

Only when I using ReactiveForms get() function:

[image]

I try to change Es Library but every time it not solved

Comment: to get the form controls form form group, use this.formGroup.controls['controlName']

Comment: @FaizanurRahman thanks so much it appear now without error

Comment: check how you defined the this.companyForm (should be `companyForm:FormGroup` and from where are you import the FormGroup (should be from`'@angular/forms'`)